# How do I change the style of an input box in IE7 on focus?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I know IE7 has issues...

I've read posts here and on Google telling me I need to set the style by hand onfocus() and onblur().  However, everything I try isn't working!

Here is my jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){                       

        if (jQuery.browser.msie === true) {

        $("input.date-picker").each(function(i) 
            {
                var $foo= $(this);
                $foo.bind('onfocus onblur', function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass('smalltxt-active');
                    });

            });                

            }//end if


     });
```

The a corresponding  box

```
<input name="ctl00$SelectionContent$Selections1$txtDestinationDate" type="text"
id="ctl00_SelectionContent_Selections1_txtDestinationDate" class="date-picker" 
style="width:80px;" />
```

I have already confirmed that my code is detecting MSIE.  That I am getting a count of 2 input.date-picker objects.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$foo.bind('onfocus onblur', function() {
```

should be

```
$foo.bind('focus blur', function() {
```

You don't need the each-loop really,

```
$("input.date-picker").bind('focusin focusout', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('smalltxt-active');
}
```

Is just fine. It will select all input elements with the class 'date-picker' and bind the events to it.
You may also want to read about the [.focusin()](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) events.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Does .bind() add code to the input element for these events?

it's not working, even with this change.  And I don't see any markup added, either (not sure if I'm supposed to)

Comment: updated. .bind() only calls an eventhandler method which binds your selfdefined code. If everything works correctly, you can use FireBug to watch the toggle of the class smalltxt-active.

Answer (score 0):

try this for many form element

$("input,select,button").bind('focusin focusout', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('focu');
});